# Reduced Density Matrix in k space

Tags: condensed-matter, density-operator, many-body

Given a many-electron wavefunction, $\Psi(x_1,...,x_N),$ the **1-particle reduced density matrix** is
$$\rho(x,x^\prime)= N \int \Psi^\ast(x,x_2,...,x_N) \Psi(x^\prime,x_2,...,x_N) dx_2...dx_N. $$
Next, imagine there is a collection of 1-particle **orthonormal** functions (orbitals) $\phi_1,\phi_2,...,\phi_M$ such that it is possible to write
$$\Psi(x_1,...,x_N) = \sum_{k_1,...,k_N} C_{k_1,..,k_N} \phi_{j_1}(x_1)...\phi_{j_N}(x_N) $$
(The coefficients $C_{k_1,..,k_N}$ have of course to be antisymmetric, so that the terms can be organized as Slater determinants and thus $\Psi$ will be antisymmetric, but for the present purpose it is more comfortable to write it like this).

I would like to construct the 1-particle reduced density matrix in k space, and my guess is that it should just be:
$$\rho_{j,k} = \sum_{j_2,...,j_N}C^\ast_{j,k_2,..,k_N}C_{k,k_2,..,k_N}, $$
but I'm not sure that's entirely correct. Indeed, if I'm not mistaken, the relationship between $\rho(x,x^\ast)$ and $\rho_{j,k}$ should be just
$$\rho(x,x^\ast) = \sum_{j,k} \rho_{j,k} \phi^\ast_{j}(x) \phi_{k}(x^\ast) $$
(a change of basis), but with the present definitions I have not been able to reach this relationship (due to the very messy and lengthy Slater determinants' algebra).

The reduced density matrix should have positive eigenvalues smaller than 1, but I am not able to show also that this $\rho_{j,k}$ I have defined must satisfy such property.
Is something missing?